# supervisor and laravel websockets not working

Tags: laravel, websocket, supervisord

I run supervisor but websockets is not working (running locally)
Can anyone help?
-supervisor Running successfully

```
[program:websockets]
command=/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/xsite.com/lower.xsite.com/artisan websockets:serve
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
```

websockets error : `WebSocket connection to 'wss://lower.xsite.com/app/abc?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.4.0&flash=false' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

Comment: Welcome to SO ... port should be 6001 and for ssl 433 which on your using

Comment: I was not using ssl because it's localhost. Do you need additional settings? (i use 'useTLS' => true)

Comment: I did what you said but my problem still persists

Comment: use `forceTLS:false` if not using ssl and `wss` it should be `ws` as your not using ssl

Comment: I have set it but the same error persists, supervisor"php artisan websockets: serve" how do I know if the service is running?

Comment: did you exposed port 6001 from you server ? `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` you can check by this port 6001 is runing or not

Comment: php       12***         root    5u  IPv4 205****      0t0  TCP *:6001 (LISTEN)

Comment: 404 error can't find url but it's correct

Comment: then may be it tries  to ssl url that's why u r getting 404

Comment: How can I set my SSL

Comment: you have 2 choice generate ssl file manually or handel by server and generate by certbot

Comment: article proposal

Comment: i don't have any article i just setup recently that's why i know this